# Storing values within an existing NSMutableDictionary structure loaded from a plist?

Tags: objective-c, plist, nsdictionary

Firstly, thank you all for your help so far, stackoverflow is a great community!!

This plist exists upon loading the application and currently looks like this:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Roast</key>
    <array>
        <array>
            <string>Chicken</string>
            <string>200c, Grill</string>
            <string>01:00</string>
            <string>chicken.jpg</string>
            <array>
                <string>00:30</string>
                <string>Baste</string>
            </array>
        </array>
        <array>
            <string>Veg</string>
            <string>200c, Grill</string>
            <string>00:20</string>
            <string>veg.jpg</string>
        </array>
        <array>
            <string>Gravy</string>
            <string>High heat pan</string>
            <string>00:10</string>
            <string>gravy.jpg</string>
            <array>
                <string>00:05</string>
                <string>Stir</string>
            </array>
        </array>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**To clarify:**

- There is one key, which is the group (Roast).
- Within there, are three arrays (one for each food item).
- Within the food items, there is an optional subtimer (applied only to Chicken and Gravy in this instance).

**What I'm trying to do:**

I would like the user to be able to add their own key, and then their items within, or to add items within an existing key. Example: User wants to add 'Green Beans' to the key: Roast with the corresponding information: Boil at medium heat, 00:10, greens.jpg.

**What I've currently done:**

Loaded the plist into a dictionary, tried saving user entries into an existing key, but it seems to just create a new key, despite using the same key value.

**Where I'm stuck:**

I'd like to find out a way to say: If there exists a key called 'Roast', then go into that key, and add the following values in the following structure. Is there an easy way to do this? Or perhaps there is a way to grab the 'location' of an existing key, then use that location to add to the mutable dictionary then store it into the plist? Perhaps I've structured it incorrectly as well? I would be very grateful if there is someone that could show me how to add values to a structure 2 levels down, then I should be able to figure it out.

In advance, many thanks for all your help so far!

Regards,
SineTwo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a plist you can from a NSMutableDictionary from plist

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"plistName" forType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];


NSMutableArray *roastItems = [dict[@"Roast"] mutableCopy];
```

You can add items to `roastItems`.

```
//Modifed roast items is added back to the root dictionary
[dict setObject:roastItems forKey:@"Roast"];
```

If you want to add a new category add a new key and corresponding value to `dict`

```
NSString *newCategoryName = @"NewCategory";
NSArray *categoryItems = //User populated array;

[dict setObject:categoryItems forKey:newCategoryName];

//Save the modified dict to plist
[dict writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

EDIT :

The structure of plist can be made into this it would be very easy to organize models

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CategoryName</key>
        <string>Roast</string>
        <key>CategoryItems</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>ItemName</key>
                <string>Chicken</string>
                <key>Type</key>
                <string>Grill</string>
                <key>Time</key>
                <string>01:00</string>
                <key>ImageName</key>
                <string>image.jpg</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

With this your root would be an array of categories. Each category has its name and items. Category Item would have name, type, time etc.

So when you want to create a new category, create a dictionary with category name and array of category items. Category item would have its own item name, type, time etc. Very clean and elegant.Any number of items can be added to category items.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Anupdas. When having made a mutable copy, how do you then 'inject' that back into the dictionary? Or even overwrite the current 'Roast'? I presume at the moment that it would `1) take the existing roast (3 items). 2) make a copy. 3) add one new item.` So I presume there would be a way to replace the 'Roast' key, or add the newly created item to the existing 'Roast' key?

Comment: Yes, you should add the modified items back to dict with same key. And may i suggest a change in your structure. For your array of items in a category, instead of keeping an array of strings you can make that it to a dictionary with keys name, time, image etc. It would be more clean

Comment: Yes, change your structure to use a dictionary!

Comment: @Anupdas, so you mean for it to look more like this:  ? Say if I then wanted to add a new dictionary to the key 'Steak' (which is an array of dictionaries), I could do this using: `[dict setObject:categoryItems forKey:@"Steak"]; //assuming categoryItems is a dictionary` ? Would that add it as Item 2 if Item 0 and 1 already exists for example?

Comment: @SineTwo I have edited my answer with a proposed change in your plist structure.

Comment: Hi @anupdas, thank you for your swift reply and your help so far! I believe this will solve it. I'll work on it tonight and report in tomorrow Sir! :)